# Warnings when restarting apache

Tags: apache2, lamp

I setup a LAMP in Ubuntu 10.10 and it seems to be working fine but a couple of things are weird. The weirdess thing is that whenever I use:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I get: 
could not reliably determine the server`s fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName.

Funny thing is that if I

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 status
```

Apache is running

So I assume everything is ok but I have to reboot the server everytime I change something since
    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Does not seem to do anything.

I am pretty lost in Ubuntu (not complete newbie but close).

Comment: @jorge castro Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a warning, the webserver usually works fine if you ignore this warning. IIRC you can resolve the warning by entering a hostname in the configuration file in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Great! Turns out I was NOT using sudo when restarting my apache server and this is why I always had to reboot. Silly me. Thanks for the prompt answer!

Answer (score 2):

**This is what worked for me when I had the same warnings**

Open your Apache config:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

And add the line:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set a ServerName in the configuration, make sure that the host name resolves to an IP via DNS or is in your `/etc/hosts` file.